# Failing to create a new group in Tangerine

Tags: web

I have hosted Tangerine on my server but I'm failing to create a new group on the web interface. It gives an error "error creating new group". I followed the installation steps on the Tangerine github repository without any problems. I installed the 3.27.8 version.